# Multiselect drop down for silverlight4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, combobox, multi-select

I m looking out for Multiselect drop down for silverlight4, one available at codeproject is targetted for silverlight3.
Any links is highly appreciated.

Comment: Most SL3 functionality should port to SL4 with minimal issues if any...

Comment: I have tried to use this, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MultiSelComboBox.aspx. This is not running unless I change target silverlight version to 3.

Comment: may be this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914405/combobox-display-value-in-silverlight

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display checkboxes as items of a comboBox, a simple DataTemplate shoud work:

```
    <ComboBox Name="combo" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Now on your code behind create an ObservableCollection ChekItem is a basic class:

```
public class CheckItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

and associate it to your comboBox ItemsSource. If you want to know what items are checked, is simple:

var checkedItems = myList.Where(i => i.IsChecked == true);